# Why the toolbar menu does not work properly with the bottom navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu, android-bottomnav

The toolbar menu was working properly until I added the bottom nav. Now the menu is hidden.
Here is the code.
This activity is a navigation drawer activity and it also has bottom nav.
when I remove the commented code (bottom nav) down below the options menu is shown.
I want to know what is the problem.

```
package com.example.aya.habtive.ui.App;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.aya.habtive.R;
import com.example.aya.habtive.ui.App.Calendar.Calendar;
import com.example.aya.habtive.ui.App.Guides.Guides;
import com.example.aya.habtive.ui.App.NewsFeeds.NewsFeeds;
import com.example.aya.habtive.ui.App.Profile.Profile;
import com.example.aya.habtive.ui.App.Tips.Tips;

public class App extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

//        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//        fragment = new NewsFeeds();
//        final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//        transaction.add(R.id.content_app, fragment).commit();
//
//        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
//                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
//
//        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
//                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
//                            case R.id.menu_home:
//                                fragment = new NewsFeeds();
//                                break;
//                            case R.id.menu_calendar:
//                                fragment = new Calendar();
//                                break;
//                            case R.id.menu_tips:
//                                fragment = new Tips();
//                                break;
//                            case R.id.menu_guides:
//                                fragment = new Guides();
//                                break;
//                            case R.id.menu_profile:
//                                fragment = new Profile();
//                                break;
//                        }
//                        final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//                        transaction.replace(R.id.content_app, fragment).commit();
//                        return true;
//                    }
//                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_notification) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here's the xml of the App.
app_side_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.habtive.ui.App.App">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="#fff"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hi! Please share your layout file and elaborate what exactly is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It would be helpful if you also add your `.xml` layout file, otherwise is hard to know how your layout is structured.

Comment: Did you fix it?